# Database Schema Viewer functionality in vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project

Recently migrated from vs 2010 -> vs 2013. Observed that there is no Database Schema Viewer in vs 2013 for DB projects. SQL Server Explorer does something similar but when you add new items (say a new table) to a project, noticed two things:
1. the new table file gets created in the root folder and not under the Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\tables\
2. In vs2010, the table scripts used to have extension XX.table.sql but in vs2013, its always XX.sql

What actions can i take to achieve the above 2 behaviors as in vs 2010

Answer (score 1):

Schema View is no longer part of Visual Studio. You'll have to use a 3rd party tool. If you have SQL Server Management Studio then you can use its database diagrams feature.

Visual Studio no longer manages the folder structure in database projects. When adding a new item, you should add it to the appropriate folder yourself.

To include the schema name in your files go to the database project's properties, select the Project Settings tab, and check **Include schema name in file name**. This change is not retroactive.